# Движение объекта при щелчке

Tags: swift

Мне нужно, чтобы при первом щелчке объект просто добавлялся на сцену (ну, это я знаю, как: `self.addChild(name)`), а при втором щелчке мне нужно, чтобы он начал двигаться, не важно в какую строну.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: сделать переменную = 0, когда происходит клик смотреть чему она равна, если 0, то добавлять объект и делать ее равной 1, если 1 то начинать двигать объект

Comment: А вот как само движение прописать? Не с помощью affectedByGravity?

Comment: Я пробовала делать так: name.position=CGPointMake(400,400)
это для первого щелчка, а для второго так писала: name.position=positionOfTouch. Но он сразу вниз падает

Comment: в чем вопрос то состоит? в кликах или траектория объекта? вы же пишете все равно в какую сторону двигаться - вот он вниз и движется

Comment: он получается при первом клике сразу падает, а мне нужно, чтобы при первом на месте стоял, а при втором падал, не могу сообразить как

Comment: я так понимаю есть какая то среда в физикой?

Comment: У меня к объекту применен  affectedByGravity=true

Comment: Покажите пример кода, так нам будет проще понять что происходит и подсказать пути решения.

Comment: при первом нажатии делайте false, при втором меняйте на true

Comment: Да собственно в коде ничего особенного https://yadi.sk/d/NlvSnA3CmV78y
А когда меняю false на true, ничего не меняется...

Comment: это слишком сложная для вас задача. начните с чего то проще, например какие то базовые алгоритмы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам после создания объекта надо где то его сохранить чтобы при втором нажатии его модифицировать

```
var bowlReference: SKShapeNode?


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let positionOfTouch = touch.locationInNode(self)



        self.number++
        if (self.number == 1) {
            let bowlUp = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 25)
            bowlUp.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 400)
            bowlUp.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
            bowlUp.physicsBody?.friction=1
            bowlUp.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
            bowlUp.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 1.5

            self.addChild(bowlUp)
            self.bowlReference = bowlUp
            bowlUp.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        }
        else if (self.number == 2){
            self.bowlReference!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
            // bowlUp.position = positionOfTouch
            self.bowlReference!.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            self.number = 0

        }

    }
}
```